# How to time out a session state variable in Yii?

Tags: php, session, yii

I create a state variable in user identity class and and use in one of actions in controller. Before using I want to check if state variable exists. i.e

In userIdentity class:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('pictures', array());//Want this variable to die after 5 mins
```

In my controller action:

```
if(isset(Yii::app()->user->pictures))
{

 //do what I want if state variable picture is set
}
```

Is there any way to set timeout for session state variables?
I know we can provide session timeouts in config file but that will logout user which is not I want. I just want to unset/destroy state variable 'pictures' after 5 minutues.

Any way to do that in Yii?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no such built-in mechanism in Yii, so

on success login:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('pictures', array());
Yii::app()->user->setState('logged_time', microtime(true));
```

before each request

```
if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('logged_time') 
&& (microtime(true) - Yii::app()->user->logged_time > 300)) {
    Yii::app()->user->setState('pictures', null); // unset pictures state
    Yii::app()->user->setState('logged_time', null); // unset logged_time if necessary
}
```